# I dropped my pentax 67 (not 6x7) and the shutter won't fire — how can I determine what's wrong?

Tags: troubleshooting, repair, pentax, diy, medium-format

I dropped it and now it will not fire. How can I diagnose the problem myself? And, once I have figured that out, how can I learn to fix it?

Comment: How to fix a camera depends on what is not working. Just dropping a camera doesn't indicate anything.

Comment: If you read the title you will see that the shutter won't fire.

Comment: Still not indicates anything. There are many parts from the button to the fire. e.g. bend, stuck or lose parts in the mechanics or electronics (if this old lady had some)
without any explicit information nobody here are able to help you. My tip: go to a camera service and take advantage of there professional service.

Answer (score 2):

A camera is a precision mechanical device with a lot of very accurately built moving parts. I'm afraid to say that, if you're asking for advice on how to diagnose the problem on the internet, then you don't have the skill needed to repair a camera. This isn't like fixing a car - it's more like repairing a Swiss watch.

By all means, try to learn - but if you value shooting with this particular camera and are not okay with the risk of absolutely destroying it, then it's best to send it to a certified Pentax repair shop.

RE: general diagnosis - you would want to check if the film advance lever was able to load the mechanism. When you fire a shot, does it feel like anything is happening? Do you get different results with other shutter speeds? Is there damage to any other component? Does your lens stop down using DoF Preview?

Again, it'd be good to do this so that you can get a feel for the overall damage. But, you should write up your findings and send the camera in to the shop.